# SQL - Replace characters with a carriage return & line feed in JSON string

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, case

I have some JSON strings, some of which match the following:

```
{"name":"Example diagnosis 1","code":"111609001","table":"SNOMEDCT","addedby":"EDnurse","dateadded":1548080768169,"qualifier":[{"name":"Qualifier","value":"Confirmed Diagnosis","code":"410605003","prefix":"[C] "},{"name":"Left/Right","value":"Bilateral","code":"51440002","suffix":" - Bilateral"}],"prefix":"[C] ","suffix":" - Bilateral"},{"name":"Example diagnosis 2","code":"371162008","table":"SNOMEDCT","addedby":"EDnurse","dateadded":1548080778007,"qualifier":[{"name":"Qualifier","value":"Confirmed Diagnosis","code":"410605003","prefix":"[C] "},{"name":"Left/Right","value":"Bilateral","code":"51440002","suffix":" - Bilateral"}],"prefix":"[C] ","suffix":" - Bilateral"}
```

I have built the following case statement, that works in part, and returns the following string with carriage returns & line breaks, replacing the comma:

```
{"name":"Example diagnosis 1","code":"111609001","table":"SNOMEDCT","addedby":"EDnurse","dateadded":1548080768169,"qualifier":[{"name":"Qualifier","value":"Confirmed Diagnosis","code":"410605003","prefix":"[C] "},{"name":"Left/Right","value":"Bilateral","code":"51440002","suffix":" - Bilateral"}],"prefix":"[C] ","suffix":" - Bilateral"}
{"name":"Example diagnosis 2","code":"371162008","table":"SNOMEDCT","addedby":"EDnurse","dateadded":1548080778007,"qualifier":[{"name":"Qualifier","value":"Confirmed Diagnosis","code":"410605003","prefix":"[C] "},{"name":"Left/Right","value":"Bilateral","code":"51440002","suffix":" - Bilateral"}],"prefix":"[C] ","suffix":" - Bilateral"}
```

Here is my CASE statement:

```
select 
     CASE 
          WHEN notevalue LIKE '%"suffix":" - Bilateral"},%'
          THEN REPLACE(substring(LEFT(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)),DATALENGTH(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)))-1), 2, 8000),'"suffix":" - Bilateral"},','"suffix":" - Bilateral"}'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
          ELSE substring(LEFT(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)),DATALENGTH(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)))-1), 2, 8000)
        END as test
from clinicalnotesdata
where notekey = 'ed diagnosis'
and visitid = '6948'
```

However, I also need it to add the other 2 instances to my CASE statement to catch other strings (which all work individually). As soon as I combine the 3 scenarios for the case, it obviously matches the 1st scenario and ends. But sometimes the strings match all 3 scenarios.

```
WHEN notevalue LIKE '%"prefix":"[[]C] "},%'
THEN REPLACE(substring(LEFT(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)),DATALENGTH(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)))-1), 2, 8000),'"prefix":"[C] "}],"prefix":"[C] "},','"prefix":"[C] "}],"prefix":"[C] "}'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))

WHEN notevalue LIKE '"%prefix":"[[]C] ","suffix":" - Right"},%'
THEN REPLACE(substring(LEFT(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)),DATALENGTH(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)))-1), 2, 8000),'"prefix":"[C] ","suffix":" - Right"},','"prefix":"[C] ","suffix":" - Right"}'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

Essentially I need to replace specific commas with CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) where all or some of the above 3 pieces of criteria are met.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using a more recent version of SQL Server, then you might want to check out the JSON API it has.  Using that might be much easier than trying to do this with base string functions.

Comment: Yeah thanks - unfortunately we are on 2014  :(

Answer (score 0):

The best why to approach this is to use a trick I call *Aliasing with APPLY*; it's my way of keeping my code DRYer (DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself). You can simplify your code like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX(a.stxt+',',t.notevalue) > 0  --WHEN t.notevalue LIKE '%"suffix":" - Bilateral"},%'
    THEN REPLACE(a2.string,a.stxt+',',a.stxt+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
    ELSE a2.string
  END as test
FROM        @clinicalnotesdata AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CAST(t.notevalue AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                    DATALENGTH(t.notevalue)-1, '"suffix":" - Bilateral"}')) AS a(nval,dl,stxt)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(LEFT(a.nval,DATALENGTH(a.nval)-1), 2, 8000))) AS a2(string)
WHERE       t.notekey = 'ed diagnosis'
AND         t.visitid = '6948';
```

This code will do exactly the same thing and, as you can see, it's much easier to understand and re-use. For example, All four instances of `CAST(t.notevalue AS VARCHAR(8000)` have been replaced with `a.nval`, two instances of `DATALENGTH(t.notevalue)-1` have been replaced with a.dl. The two instances of: `substring(LEFT(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)),DATALENGTH(cast(notevalue as varchar(8000)))-1), 2, 8000)` are now removed.

As you can see, I'm using the VALUES constructor and APPLY to create inline functions that simply alias repeated chunks of code. Trust me, start writing your code like this and it becomes much easier to do things that would otherwise cause you to pull your hair out.

Comment: Hi Alan, that is very helpful and is indeed much cleaner - thank you. The only issue is that it still only lets me apply 1 filter at a time - I need to apply 3 or 4 filters, to catch all instances of the string.